# QGIS Advanced Python Field Calculator Syntax

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, error, syntax

I am attempting to calculate the difference between two azimuths using the following code in the QGIS Advanced Python Field Calculator :

```
def azimuthDifference():
    Model_Azimuth = <Model_Azimuth>
    RMSTraffic_Azimuth = <RMSTraffic_Azimuth>

    diff = RMSTraffic_Azimuth - Model_Azimuth
    absDiff = abs(diff)

    if absDiff == 180:
        return absDiff
    elif absDiff < 180:
        return diff
    elif RMSTraffic_Azimuth > Model_Azimuth:
        return absDiff - 360
    else:
        return 360 - absDiff
value = azimuthDifference()
```

When I run the model that it is a part of, I receive the following error message:

```
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "<string>", line 5, in azimuthDifference
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

When I set the `Model_Azimuth` and `RMSTraffic_Azimuth` variables to integers (e.g. `Model_Azimuth = 45`), the code executes without any error, so I believe my problem is related to pulling the attribute values for the feature using `<Model_Azimuth>`.